# SQL Query to sum fields from different tables

Tags: sql, select, join, sum

I'm a humble programmer that hates SQL ... :) Please help me with this query.

I have 4 tables, for example:

```
Table A:
Id Total
1  100
2  200
3  500

Table B
ExtId  Amount
1      10
1      20
1      13
2      12
2      43
3      43
3      22

Table C
ExtId  Amount
1      10
1      20
1      13
2      12
2      43
3      43
3      22

Table D
ExtId  Amount
1      10
1      20
1      13
2      12
2      43
3      43
3      22
```

I need to make a SELECT that shows the Id, the Total and the SUM of the Amount fields of tables B, C and D like this

```
Id Total AmountB AmountC AmountD
1  100   43      43      43
2  200   55      55      55
3  500   65      65      65
```

I've tried with a inner join of the three tables by the Id and doing a sum of the amount fields but results are not rigth. Here is the wrong query:

```
SELECT     dbo.A.Id, dbo.A.Total, SUM(dbo.B.Amount) AS Expr1, SUM(dbo.C.Amount) AS  Expr2, SUM(dbo.D.Amount) AS Expr3
FROM         dbo.A INNER JOIN
                  dbo.B ON dbo.A.Id = dbo.B.ExtId INNER JOIN
                  dbo.C ON dbo.A.Id = dbo.C.ExtId INNER JOIN
                  dbo.D ON dbo.A.Id = dbo.D.ExtId
GROUP BY dbo.A.Id, dbo.A.Total
```

Thanks in advance, its just that I hate SQL (or that SQL hates me).

EDIT: I had a typo. This query is not giving the right results. Extended the example.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Or you can take advantage of using SubQueries:

```
select A.ID, A.Total, b.SB as AmountB, c.SC as AmountC, d.SD as AmountD
from A
  inner join (select ExtID, sum(Amount) as SB from B group by ExtID) b on A.ID = b.ExtID
  inner join (select ExtID, sum(Amount) as SC from C group by ExtID) c on c.ExtID = A.ID
  inner join (select ExtID, sum(Amount) as SD from D group by ExtID) d on d.ExtID = A.ID
```

Comment: I really liked your approach. Clean, simple ... and it works! Thanks .. but i'm still hatting SQL :P

Answer (score 3):

From your description, this query should give you an error as you are using the non-existent column `dbo.A.Amount` in your group by. Changing this to `dbo.A.Total` might be what you need.

If you need all the amounts together, then try this query:

```
select A.Id, A.Total, sum(B.Amount + C.Amount + D.Amount) AS Total_Amount
from A
  inner join B on A.Id = B.ExtId
  inner join C on A.Id = C.ExtId
  inner join D on A.Id = D.ExtId
group by A.Id, A.Total;
```

Comment: This is the best answer, as this query should perform faster as it can be optimized by SQL Server since it doesn't contain nested queries.

Answer (score 2):

This one also works well

`SELECT (SELECT   SUM(Amount)  FROM TableA) AS AmountA,
            (SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM TableB) AS AmountB,
            (SELECT SUM(Amount)  FROM TableC) AS AmountC,
            (SELECT SUM(Amount)  FROM TableD) AS AmountD`

Answer (score 0):

This might help other users.

```
SELECT Total=(Select Sum(Amount) from table a)+(Select Sum(Amount) from table b)+(Select Sum(Amount) from table c)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code
SELECT Total=isnull((Select Sum(Isnull(Amount,0)) from table a),0)+isnull((Select Sum(isnull(Amount,0)) from table b),0)+isnull((Select Sum(isnull(Amount,0)) from table c),0)