# Sum between 3 linked tables SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to pull a sum from linked table.

**Order**:

```
OrderID     LocationID  OrderDate
100         1           1/1/2000
200         2           1/2/2000
```

**OrderedItems**:

```
ID          OrderID     ItemID
1           100         1
2           200         2
3           200         2
4           100         3
```

**OrderItem**:

```
ItemID      ItemName    Cost
1           Mobile1     100.00
2           Mobile2     200.00
3           Mobile3     300.00
```

The `Order` table is effectively a group of `OrderedItems`. Each row in `OrderedItems` links back to `OrderItem` via the `ItemID`.

I am trying to add a column to the below query for order total.

```
Order Number    Location    Date Ordered    Order Total
-------------------------------------------------------
100             Sydney      1/1/2000        400
200             Brisbane    1/2/2000        400
```

The current query I have is:

```
SELECT  
    Order.OrderID AS [Order Number],
    OL.Name AS [Location],
    Order.OrderDate AS [Date Ordered]
FROM
    Order
LEFT JOIN 
    Office_Locations AS OL ON OL.id = Order.LocationID
```

I have tried to follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301647/sql-query-to-sum-fields-from-different-tables) however I am needing to link through 3 tables for the values to add.

Any hep would be great!

Comment: This is atypical schema... not necessarily wrong, but not usual, either. It's much more normal to have a qty field in the OrderedItems table than it is to repeat the item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not finding a sum from three tables. You're finding a sum from **one** table: the OrderItem table. The only trick is getting the `JOIN` and `GROUP BY` expressions done correctly to make that column available.

```
SELECT o.OrderID As [Order Number], l.Name As Location
    , o.OrderDate As [Date Ordered], SUM(i.Cost) As [Order Total]
FROM [Order] o
INNER JOIN Office_Locations l on l.id = o.LocationID
INNER JOIN OrderedItems oi on oi.OrderID = o.OrderID
INNER JOIN OrderItem i ON i.ItemID = oi.ItemID
GROUP BY o.OrderID, l.Name, o.OrderDate
```

[**SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/84fa54/2)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `SUM` to get the total `Cost`:

<kbd>[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0f2f1/1/0)</kbd>

```
SELECT
    [Order Number]  = o.OrderID,
    Location        = ol.Name,
    [Date Ordered]  = o.OrderDate,
    [Order Total]   = SUM(i.Cost)
FROM [Order] o
INNER JOIN OrderedItems oi
    ON oi.OrderId = o.OrderId
INNER JOIN OrderItem i
    ON i.ItemID = oi.ItemID
LEFT JOIN Office_Locations ol
    ON ol.id = o.LocationID
GROUP BY
    o.OrderID, o.OrderDate, ol.Name
```

As commented by Joel Coehoorn, it's more normal to have a `quantity` field in the `OrderedItems` table than to repeat them. Following his advise, your `OrderedItems` table should be:

```
ID          OrderID     ItemID  Quantity
1           100         1       1
2           200         2       2
3           100         3       1
```

Additional Notes:

- Use meaningful aliases to improve readability.
- Refrain from using reserved words as your object names i.e. `Order` could be renamed as `OrderHeader`.